# ggplot 2 graph with two series from differing length dataframes and different dash types

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following data consisting of two data.frames of differing lengths.

```
df1 <- data.frame(cbind(rnorm(20,0.4,0.2), seq(0,200,by=10)))
df2 <- data.frame(cbind(rnorm(30,0.6,0.25), seq(0,270,by=9)))
```

I would like to plot them on the same plot and have them distinguished from each other by different types of dashed lines. I can't seem to get this to work and have rather extensively searched for a solution. The trouble is that my two sets of data are of different lengths, therefore I cannot simply melt the data and stick into ggplot.

```
ggplot() + 
  geom_path(data = df1, aes(x = X1, y = X2)) +
  geom_path(data = df2, aes(x = X1, y = X2)) +
  theme_bw() + geom_point() + geom_line() +
  scale_y_reverse()+
  scale_x_continuous(position="top") +
  scale_linetype_manual(values=c("twodash", "dotted")) +
  theme(axis.line=element_line(),
        axis.line.y = element_line(),
        panel.background= element_blank(),
        panel.border = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor.x = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major.y = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor.y = element_blank())
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that the data have different lengths doesn't really matter here, you just need to create a new column that identifies which dataset is which and you can stack them on top of each other with `rbind()`:

```
df1$Source = "df1"
df2$Source = "df2"

df_combined = rbind(df1, df2)

ggplot(df_combined, aes(x = X1, y = X2, linetype = Source)) + 
    geom_path() +
    theme_bw() +
    scale_y_reverse()+
    scale_x_continuous(position="top") +
    scale_linetype_manual(values=c("twodash", "dotted")) +
    theme(axis.line=element_line(),
          axis.line.y = element_line(),
          panel.background= element_blank(),
          panel.border = element_blank(),
          panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),
          panel.grid.minor.x = element_blank(),
          panel.grid.major.y = element_blank(),
          panel.grid.minor.y = element_blank())
```

Comment: Oh, that was simple! I've been stumped all morning! Thanks :)